# Output is Float not Integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am new to programming and python specifically. I want the output to be integers with no decimal

I have tried adding return statements but I am getting a conversion error. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
def collatz(number):
    while number != 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number = number / 2
        elif number % 2 != 0:
            number = 3 * number + 1
        print(number)

print('Enter number:')
collatzNumber = input()
collatzNumber = int(collatzNumber)
collatz(collatzNumber)
```

Results:

```
Enter number:                 
3
10
5.0
16.0
8.0
4.0
2.0
1.0
```

```
Expected: 
3 
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
```

Comment: you can either replace `/` (float division) with `//` (integer division), or (in the function), replace `print(number)` with `print(int(number))` (which will convert the float to an int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/` true division operator always returns `float`s, however using `//` floor division operator will return an `int`eger.

Full code:

```
def collatz(number):
    while number != 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number = number // 2
        elif number % 2 != 0:
            number = 3 * number + 1
        print(number)

print('Enter number:')
collatzNumber = input()
collatzNumber = int(collatzNumber)
collatz(collatzNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the advice of Benjamin Cohen.
Either replace `/` (float division) with `//` (integer division),
or in the function replace `print(number)` with `print(int(number))`.

Comment: It's called floor division not integer division

Comment: And the other is true division

Comment: Oh i guess you did google translate to get Benjamin Cohen, from בנימין כהן

Answer (score 0):

As others explained, from python 3 `/` does a true division (in float). Check "Division and Type Conversion" in this link - https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Operators.

To have the floor division use `//`